# what is difference between using system.window.shapes and using system.IO?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am newbie in window presentation foundation and c# technology. I had a situation like, I am  using shape and IO , when i use path some conflict-ion are occur, what should i do ? can I used it both in one page. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.IO.Path is Path to a File

where as Drawing path is path as a shape.

You can use fully qualified namespace like this -

```
System.IO.Path myFilePath;
```

Comment: any other ideas like if i don't want to use fully qualified namespace

Comment: well you can use name space aliases, but i am interested in knowing y you do not want to use fully qualified namespace ? . post your code for more clarity

Comment: A working code is never UGLY :)..... altho there can be a pretty way of doing it.... clink on following link to learn about Namespace Aliases https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Comment: its still not marked as answer..Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71863/discussion-between-muds-and-dhru-soni).